# How do I mass edit serval lines with Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, edit

is there any way I can delete words in a specific line, after a specific character is there? Example:

12345:6789

tjweaiv:tkojeatkasdf

1237ujb:5bji11s

kv120ki12:tj3i2tm23

is there a way that I can delete everything that comes after : ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following find replacement:

**Find:**

```
^(.*:).*$
```

**Replace:**

```
$1
```

Choose the replace all option if you want to do this replacement on every line.  Also, make sure that you are in regex mode when doing this replacement, otherwise it won't work as intended.

**Update:**

If you wanted to retain everything coming before the *first* colon, then you could make the find regex non greedy and use this:

```
^(.*?:).*$
```

Comment: u got a idea how i do it with between 2 of the same characters? example:

Comment: tbjioweatjioweadf:12345: your option only deletes after the last one

Comment: So you want to retain everything before the _first_ colon?  Is that right?

Comment: exactly, i have different types of txts that i have to edit but that should cover the most

Comment: is there also a way to delete every line that doesn't have a specific character in it? for example delete every line that doesnt include the character @